# Why is this a bad question-?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Where is the value when I do this in pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748749/where-is-the-value-when-i-do-this-in-pandas-series)

The question is clear, concise and includes a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

It's also non-trivial for those unfamiliar with `pandas` syntax.

The question quickly generated 5 downvotes and I'm wondering *what needs to be done* to improve the quality of the question.

I searched for duplicates, but couldn't find any, possibly because I didn't know what to search for.

Comment: Well I don't know Panda but I agree that the question looks good to me. I wish all new users posted questions that were this good.

Comment: Just speculating, but they may have come due to the original version of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49748749/1 which was lacking code formatting, capitalization, and was overall hard to read.

Comment: +1. Hypotheses: It might have gotten into the first posts queue, where users who may've been unable to close it for any reason decided to just downvote and move on since it didn't ask an explicit question.

Comment: @BradLarson: it was edited into good(-ish) shape in under 2 minutes, though. Even after 6 minutes there was just one downvote.

Comment: I agree this is a fine question. Better than so much of what the Pandas tag has become these days.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Appreciate the advice about tagging & explicit question. I hope OP wasn't pushed away by the initial negative response, because these kinds of questions have wider use. If this is due to first posts queue reviewers, then I'd be especially disappointed (as this is *exactly* what they should *not* be dismissing).

Comment: Only the last revision (~6 hours after asking the question) add the explicit question. It was a bit hard to understand before that.

Comment: @user202729 Okay; but that last revision was not done by the OP. It was done by someone who decided to think and edit rather than downvote. Worth mentioning, IMO.

Comment: @Gimby, just a hunch but OP probably ran away after getting 5 downvotes and no response. Anyone involved in `[python]` / `[pandas]` tags should have picked up that the improvement could easily be edited in without making assumptions.

Comment: @Gimby Hm... the edit is good, but the downvotes are not wrong. The downvotes indicates _something_ is wrong with the post. Definitely a comment explaining what is wrong helps in this case, because it may be not obvious to someone.

Comment: @user202729 Looks much worse to me - it isn't well intentioned as much as it is a rant.