# Detect I'm new/go easy/thank you/I hope... in questions

Tags: feature-request, quality-improvement

Would it be possible to detect phrases from the title (thank yous and go easy type, possibly a dynamic growing list) in questions, and when said user goes to post after the initial click have a pop up (like the no-tag one) suggesting something along the lines of

> "We have detected [phrases] in your question. SO is centered around good programming content, and these usually only clutter the question and are discouraged. Consider removing these for the benefit of everyone. [link to some guideline post]"

Detection once per question only, so if a user insists he can (I have no idea why). This does not even need to be regex, just a case-insensitive detection ignoring whitespace. If the phrases could be community moderated (say taken from a post somewhere) that would be even better.

This would perhaps alleviate some of the appeared disgruntlement in Meta and the recent "hot" blog post, and make it easier for everyone, so win-win.

This follows [How can we encourage (new) authors to ask confident questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) - encouragement should be more proactive in my opinion.

Comment: there is already something there for titles and in the body for *only code*. Maybe that allows for extension to what you propose. IIRC the other options are implemented with a regex, some of which can be added / configured at runtime by a CM.

Comment: @rene I saw, hopefully this means this would be super easy to add then.

Comment: Related (and a good discussion): [*How can we encourage (new) authors to ask confident questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366264/2751851). Point #4 under the "Questions" header is similar to this feature request.

Comment: @duplode I was looking for that! I knew I saw it somewhere, thanks.

Comment: Just a thought.. I find a lot thanks only answers. This could be extended to that

Comment: "Solved", "Fixed", "Updated", "Plz Delete"...

Comment: Was just reminded of some more "I'm new/a beginner/a noob", tips, welcome.

Comment: if stack overflow is having a problem encouraging women and people of color to participate, why would policing unconfident language (arising mostly because we are made to feel like we don't belong here/are "noobs") and telling them they are essentially unconfident & thus inexperienced encourage more confident questions?

Comment: @astrocat1997 looks likes you are [conflating newbies with woman/people of color (ha?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color).

Comment: @kabanus im not. im acknowledging that women and people of color are punished more for beginner mistakes/not having the same (programming in this case) experiences as white men would be, and thus reasonably feel less confident and more "noobish" or display behaviors that fit this stereotype because thats what we're expected to show and is easiest to perform subconsciously, hence why policing unconfident language doesn't actually work and just discourages women and people of color from participating further.

Comment: @astrocat1997 "people of color" is an american term. For people from countries where everyone is on what you call a "color" spectrum, this phrase doesn't even make sense. I can't  speak to the women part, but I did not find myself particularly mistreated when I started on SO. To prove what you are trying to say you would have to make a census of women and see if they identify a trend of mistreatment. In any case, the white/color thing is for colonial countries, and not even most of them anymore. Attributing this split of humanity to everyone is offensive, and doesn't even make sense.

Comment: you're right, im talking from an american perspective, and that was ignorant to generalize to the whole of people on this site and wrongly assume a huge expanse of experiences like that and im sorry about that. from my american perspective, i see this kind of hostile environment to women and people of color in a lot of tech cultures around the country and in spaces with a lot of western influence, like here on stack overflow. i see this is still a problem, however, when we look at this with a more international perspective and know that there are a **lot** of marginalized people, and one...

Comment: @kabanus ...part of marginalization is making people feel like they can't participate in society. so when we are overly critical of newcomers and restrict their access, we disproportionately affect marginalized people, who might be turned away because their society has made them feel less confident in themselves and that their contributions are unwelcome/useless.

Comment: @astrocat1997 Well said, and I appreciate the apology. I completely agree that women and any group that has been discriminated for over decades and centuries experience an added, often subconscious, push back in some industries and companies - what amounts to prejudice (of all variants). I hope, and I think, that in SO it is not the case as a rule, while I can understand the real hesitation of such a newcomer, and how such added bad experiences can affect any new social interaction with a group. Thank you for your constructive comments.

Comment: @astrocat1997: I am the author of the linked _Meta_ question. In relation to "language policing", that was not my intent, though it is certainly an interesting aspect to consider. The thesis of my post was that some users are not confident about approaching Stack Overflow, and where that lack of confidence shows in their writing, their readership interprets the material as pleading, and becomes irritated by it, and gives the nervous author a hard time (either in the comments, or in voting, or by skipping the question).

Comment: I wanted (and still want) to investigate this phenomenon, and if any changes were to be made, I'd be happy to ask for practical changes either of writers (and how they word things) or readers (and how they interpret things). That said, I think the first category is much easier to achieve than the second category (since adding a feedback device in the editor is much easier than changing reader's attitudes or asking them to be more patient!).

Comment: Of course, if we tried a wording filter to trim language that might be regarded as obsequious, and we found that in practice it made minority inclusion even harder, then I would be opposed to it. My hope would be that diversity issues would be _improved_ by this device, since affected groups would find that their beginners questions would have less reason to attract negative/discouraging responses (and thus more of them would be answered).

Comment: @halfer Wholeheartedly agree, but I did not see any data back then to support any exclusion bias, so I am not sure how we can compare now that all these changes have already been made.

Answer (score 2):

I want to address my request, and what it will help with.

I have noticed recently when I start reading a question starting with a wall of text (could just be a paragraph, I have deteriorated somewhat in my joy of reading questions) explaining how OP is appreciative, new, just learning, or elaborating in what specific course they received an assignment:

**I just ignore the question and move on.**

- I cannot vote on it, since I did not manage to get to the meat of it.
- I cannot vote to close since I do not know if there is a reason to.
- For these reasons I cannot answer.
- I can't even give a helpful comment.

Basically I leave the question untouched, completely unable (in my laziness?) to provide any help, to OP or the community. As a side effect it makes my rest time on SO a little bit worse.

Helping users write good questions, will not just help them, it will help them squared! Also probably it will make SO more fun for me (and people who enjoy the questions and answering them).

Comment: As a side note - if this happens to enough others, it will leave SO littered with 0 score, 0 response questions.

Comment: There is a roomba script that will delete 0 score, 0 responses, 1 year old, few views, 0-1 comment: [RemoveAbandonedQuestions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

Comment: @Cœur Oddly enough, I had some tumbleweed questions way over a year - is this new? Anyway I deleted them myself. I would say it's a matter of flux - if the flux of untouched questions is large and consistent, then it won't matter after a year.

Answer (score -12):

That [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1) suggests to allow those phrases

> "Maybe it’s time we re-visited things like our “no pleases or thank yous’” rule. (It serves a valuable purpose by keeping signal high, but also suggests that we just might be Zuckerbots who aren’t even trying very hard to pass as actual humans)"

Apparently nowadays keeping this a high quality low noise Q&A is less important than peoples feelings so I don't think SO team is going to be interested in your(good) suggestion.

Comment: I read that part (combined with some previous text) more as ... people are bewildered when we tell them to delete [phrase]... - if the system (an actual bot) politely explains the reasoning perhaps it will serve to keep morale high while noise low.

Comment: Also, I did not link to the post on purpose, I don't see the point of people revisiting/finding that.